# How can I get the specific quantity and compare to the input value?

Tags: vue.js

I'm doing the validation for our system. I want to avoid the user to enter more than the maximum quantity of specific medicine. The validation is fine if I have only one row. The problem came if I have more than one row in my table. I enter 29 to the input which is less than 30. But it's giving me an alert message that I exceed the maximum quantity. I have two rows the first has the quantity of 25 and the last is 30. I notice that it also compares the first row. What should I do? Please help me with my problem.

```
var found = true;
for (var index = 0; index < this.gulod_medicines.length; index++) {
  if(this.gulod_transaction_quantity > this.gulod_medicines[index].quantity) {
    alert("You exceed the maximum quantity");
    found = false;
  }
  this.showBeneficiaryTransaction = false;

  console.log(this.gulod_transaction_quantity);
  console.log(this.gulod_medicines[index].quantity);
  console.log(found);
  console.log(this.gulod_medicines);
}

if (found) {
  this.gulod_transactions.push({...this.gulod_transaction_purchase});
  this.showBeneficiaryTransaction = true;
}
```

Comment: What's the output of the `console.log` statements?

Comment: @Richard de Wit `29 25 false >Array(2) 29 30 false >Array(2)`

Comment: I would recommend using the html elements inline form validation which can be found here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation
You can set min/max on the number being input (as well as set to a number)